# trying to auto override JS and HTML files

Tags: angularjs

i'm developning a system whit AngularJS, and as many knows the js and html files are storaged on browser's cache, sometimes making changes to the code, I've had to clear the cache to make the changes visible.. The problem is when the system is online there are no way to clear the client cache, unless he do it by himself, and as a consequence in some cases the system will not work correctly until he does.

Is there any way by means of the code to cause these cached files to be replaced by new ones?

PD: i know that the browsers have a function that replace old files but sometimes it not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a time stamp at the end of your JavaScript and HTML file requests. For example, `yourdomain.com/somescript.js?ts=1352627181` this will make sure that every time the client will make a different request. Therefore, it won't be cached by the browser. Also, you can add `no-cache` to the headers of the responses made by your server.

Comment: yea it should work, on my case i'll have to do it on a function because i dont want to clear the client files allways.. only when i make updates on code.. why? because i want to keep the speed of the response when the files are cached... and only override them when necessary..

Comment: For that, I recommend you have a timestamp on your server side (which you can change every time you deploy your new code) and send it to the client in the first request. This way, the client will have this timestamp and make every request with it, unless you change something on your server side, this timestamp won't change so that client can cache files for a while.